# Thermowell NPT at 70bar

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Is it safe to use a 1/2" NPT connection for thermowells when the process  pressure is  70 bar and temperature is about 85°C  ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is **not** an **electrical** engineering question...

Comment: As long as it's about instrumentation, I think that electrical engineering is the closest field

Comment: But it's not about instrumentation, is it? It's about what kind of pipe thread can be used at high pressure and high temperature, isn't it? Is there any part of this question that is about volts or amperes or hertz?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because pressure-resistant engineering of pipe connectors is not electrical engineering. Mechanical engineering would be the discipline I'd look into, seeing that the problem is mechanical in nature.

Comment: I'm changing to mechanical engineering

Comment: Have you found any standards for 1/2" NPT?

Comment: No, but it does exist

Comment: So you have a 1/2" NPT thread in your pressure vessel and you intend to screw a thermowell into that? Or do you plan to tap a thread into an existing pressure vessel?

Comment: ActuallyThe thermowell will be screwed in a pipeline

Comment: According to ASME 31.x piping codes, NPT is to be avoided in high pressure piping. I would guess its not rating for that kind of pressure, but do you have a specific model and a datasheet?

Comment: No, I have a 4'' line and a 2''or 3/2'' flanged well would be too much for just 4'' since it will be drilled. So we're thinking to make a 1/2 npt instead

Comment: Threads sounds like it may not be the best option. B31.x piping codes above are a great point of reference.